# How to get tuple values into a dictionary by using parameters of a function in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples, swift-playground

I have an objective to use a playground and show monthly temperatures (ex. January high temp of 30, low temp of -2) and it needs to use an array of strings as well as a dictionary with tuple values for the temperatures.

So far I have an array of strings `Months: [String]` with the months in it. As well as a dictionary of `Temperatures: [String, (temp1: Int, temp2: Int)`. I have a function `SetMonthlyTemp(month: String, temp1: Int, temp2: Int)` which I am trying to use to set the dictionary up but i can't figure out how to do so. I'm totally new to dictionaries and only used a tuple once last week and that was as a standalone property. Any help regarding setting up this dictionary to intake a tuple `(Int, Int)` would be great! Obviously there will be a display method that prints the results but I am not having any trouble finding information for that.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you posted the code.

Comment: I can do that in a few hours. Currently at work, but had lunch and wanted to post ahead of time before I get home. Or I may get time to do it by hand before then

Comment: `Class YearlyTemps
{ 
    var Months: [String]
    var Temperatures: [String,(temp1: Int, temp2: Int)] = [:]

    func SetMonthlyTemps(month: String, temp1: Int, temp2:
    Int) -> Void
    {
          //jumbled mess here that I can't figure how to populate dictionary
    }

    func ShowResult() -> Void
    {
         //wrong print here as I am not using a key yet
    }
} ` sorry for the mess in the comment but mobile on here sucks

Comment: For future reference, edit your question and add the code there instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: I tried but it is horrible trying to put code in on mobile. Holy cow. I had it all typed out but it kept denying my edit due to 4 spaces for indents but I even checked it over and still got rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy:

```
var temperatures = [String: (Int, Int)]()
temperatures["Jan"] = (10, 20)
temperatures["Feb"] = (-1, -16)
// setting temp 1 for January (note: "Jan" entry must exist in dictionary)
temperatures["Jan"]?.0 = 30

// setter ;)
func setMonthlyTemp(month: String, temp1: Int, temp2: Int) {
    temperatures[month] = (temp1, temp2)
}
```

Accessing:

```
temperatures["Feb"]      // whole tuple for February
temperatures["Jan"]?.0   // first temperature for January
temperatures["Feb"]?.1   // second temperature for February
```

Comment: Wow that easy to populate the dictionary? Now I just have to figure out how to call it all in order using an array of months as the key! Since you can't sort the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective if you are working with constrained data set e.g. month, weeks, categories of something, I don't know then it's better to use enum which will describe your data much better then tuples & string

```
enum Month {
  case january
  case february
//  ...
  case november
  case december

  static let allMonths = [january, february, /*...*/ november, december]
}

struct MonthlyTemperature {
  let month: Month
  var lowestTemp: Double?
  var highestTemp: Double?

  init(month: Month, lowest: Double? = nil, highest: Double? = nil) {
    self.month = month
    self.lowestTemp = lowest
    self.highestTemp = highest
  }
}

let temparatures = [MonthlyTemperature]()
// ...
var dict = Dictionary(grouping: temparatures, by: { $0.month })

Month.allMonths.forEach { month in
  dict.updateValue(dict[month] ?? [], forKey: month)
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that works great and all but I have to use certain objects and functions for this objective

Comment: @Noobprogrammer626 it's just more flexible and decorative rather then tuples